# How to run an Arduino project on an FPGA

Tags: arduino, fpga, xilinx, spartan

I have an Arduino project and I want to run it on an FPGA (I prefer a Spartan Board), but i am not familiar with a method doing something like that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes, someone can help you.

Comment: Does this makes any sense? Arduino is ATMEL microprocessor based, not FPGA!

Comment: I dont know if it makes any sense, that's why i asked the question, can anyone help me or not?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. FPGA's are configured using a HDL (VHDL or Verilog typically), **not** c (ignoring the fact the Arduino version of c is heavily reliant on libraries). FPGA's are also fundamentally different to micro controllers. You would typically use a micro to *control* something, whereas an FPGA is better suited to heavy parallel processing.

Yes, theoretically you could create a soft-core processor in the FPGA, but it sounds like you need to read up on FPGA's and rethink why you want to do this.

If you really want to convert C to HDL's there are some tools out there, mostly very expensive, but [here](http://www.c-to-verilog.com/) is a free one. But I can't vouch for it, I've never used it. I doubt it handles importing the Arduino C libraries, so you would also have to convert your sketch in to vanilla microcontroller C. There are probably guides on the web for that.

Comment: Can the Microblaze help me. If the answer is yes, how?

Comment: It may help you, but you still cant just simply port over your code, it would likely require heavy modification. What exactly are you doing with your Arduino? If you lack processing power it would be a lot simpler just to step up to a bigger micro (an arduino MEGA or just a bigger vanilla AVR)

Comment: i am trying to make a floppy music project. Make floppy drivers sing a midi. [Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Musical-Floppy-Drives/step3/Test-your-floppy-drives/) is the arduino project

Comment: @an an, You are seemingly a pioneer blazing a new trail, others will turn to you for help when you have found a solution

Comment: I cannot see any reason why you would want run this on an FPGA. It's not like you're doing heavy video encoding or anything, you're just switching some IO. Exactly what micros are good at! What do you hope to gain over using a micro? If you just want to play around and learn VHDL then have a look for some beginners tutorials.

Comment: Then the best thing is to have a look at some VHDL tutorials and then try to implement what you want. [Here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese171/vhdl/vhdl_primer.html) is a in depth tutorial. I've also edited the answer linking to a converter tool. No idea how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can port a soft processor to your FPGA and run C code on it. There's a project called [FPGArduino](http://www.nxlab.fer.hr/fpgarduino/) that allows you to download Arduino code directly from the Arduino IDE to the FPGA.

They have a set of supported boards, but if your specific board is not listed you can still try to port it. No VHDL/Verilog knowledge needed if you have one of the listed boards.